# No abbr for 2014 citations in dcu bibtex style

Tags: bibtex

I'm using dcu style (on harvard style) as obligatory. I just found an issue hard to pass. Problem is with more than four authors articles from 2014 (just this year!). So in the text for 5 authors bibtex entry it looks like this:
(Surname1 et al., 2010) - perfectly fine for 5 authors,
but 
(Surname1, Surname2, Surname3, Surname4, Surname5, 2014) - this no abbr type occurs just for the 2014! Both are exactly the same in bibtex file, just with the difference in year. For all other years is just fine with abbr. BTW abbr option is included in the \usepackage.

Journal class with files - https://www.amcs.uz.zgora.pl/downloads/Class_AMCS.zip

And the bibtex I used.

```
@article{2012,
  title={Some title},
  journal={Some Journal},
  author={Blazewicz, Jacek and Cheriere, Nathanael and Dutot, Pierre-Francois and Musial, Jedrzej and Trystram, Denis},
  year={2012}
}

@article{2014,
  title={Some title},
  journal={Some Journal},
  author={Blazewicz, Jacek and Cheriere, Nathanael and Dutot, Pierre-Francois and Musial, Jedrzej and Trystram, Denis}, 
  year={2014}
}

@article{2014_2,
      title={Some title 2},
      journal={Some Journal 2},
      author={Blazewicz, Jacek and Cheriere, Nathanael and Dutot, Pierre-Francois and Musial, Jedrzej and Trystram, Denis}, 
      year={2014}
    }
```

I have more bibtex possitions with the same set of authors from the same year. I see the problem with the first name. Is like bibtex cannot create few occurance with (Blazewicz et al., 2014). But is should automatically add a, b, c and so on at the end of the year.
Any suggestions?:)
doctus

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) without some code it is hard to help. We'd like a minimal working example, i.e. the smallest possible document you can provide that also show the problem you are having.

Comment: When I was preparing short example everything goes OK (dcu and harvard) - so it must be some issue with the document class provided by the journal:(

Comment: Then post the example with the journal document class plus a link to where it can be downloaded

Comment: OK, added some link and more comments.